# Como incrementar inteiros de tailSet em TreeSet<AtomicInteger> sem addAll()?

Tags: java

Tenho a seguinte parte de uma classe:

```
private TreeSet<AtomicInteger> offsets;

// ...

public void addIndex(int index) {
    SortedSet<AtomicInteger> set = offsets.tailSet(new AtomicInteger(index), false);
    AtomicInteger[] backup = set.toArray(new AtomicInteger[0]);
    set.clear();
    for (AtomicInteger i : backup) {
        i.incrementAndGet();
    }

    offsets.addAll(Arrays.asList(backup));
}
```

addIndex() basicamente incrementa todos os índices depois de `index` do conjunto. A minha pergunta é: eu posso trocar o método para este?

```
public void addIndex(int index) {
    SortedSet<AtomicInteger> set = offsets.tailSet(new AtomicInteger(index));
    for (AtomicInteger i : set) {
        i.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Pois os inteiros ainda estão em ordem, então o TreeSet ainda estaria certo. Mas isso altera os elementos por fora do TreeSet, então estou em dúvida.